# Relational behavior against a NoSQL document store for ODBC support

Tags: odbc, data-modeling, marklogic, business-intelligence, nosql

The first assertion is that document style nosql databases such as MarkLogic and Mongo should store each piece of information in a nested/complex object.

Consider the following model

```
<patient>
    <patientid>1000</patientid>
    <firstname>Johnny</firstname>
    <claim>
        <claimid>1</claimid>
        <claimdate>2015-01-02</claimdate>
        <charge><amount>100</amount><code>374.3</code></charge>
        <charge><amount>200</amount><code>784.3</code></charge>
    </claim>
    <claim>
        <claimid>2</claimid>
        <claimdate>2015-02-02</claimdate>
        <charge><amount>300</amount><code>372.2</code></charge>
        <charge><amount>400</amount><code>783.1</code></charge>
    </claim>
</patient>
```

In the relational world this would be modeled as a patient table, claim table, and claim charge table.

Our primary desire is to simultaneously feed downstream applications with this data, but also perform analytics on it. Since we don't want to write a complex program for every measure, we should be able to put a tool on top of this. For example Tableau claims to have a native connection with MarkLogic, which is through ODBC.

When we create views using range indexes on our document model, the SQL against it in MarkLogic returns excessive repeating results. The charge numbers are also double counted with sum functions. It does not work.

The thought is that through these index, view, and possibly fragment techniques of MarkLogic, we can define a semantic layer that resembles a relational structure.

The documentation hints that you should create 1 object per table, but this seems to be against the preferred document db structure.

What is the data modeling and application pattern to store large amounts of document data and then provide a turnkey analytics tool on top of it?

If the ODBC connection is going to always return bad data and not be aware of relationships, then all of the tools claiming to have ODBC support against NoSQL is not true.

References

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/setup

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/tableau

http://www.marklogic.com/press-releases/marklogic-and-tableau-build-connection/

https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/arch/data-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question: "What is the data modeling and application pattern to store large amounts of document data and then provide a turnkey analytics tool on top of it?"

The rule of thumb I use is that when I want to count "objects", I model them as separate documents. So if you want to run queries that count patients, claims, and charges, you would put them in separate documents.

That doesn't mean we're constraining MarkLogic to only relational patterns. In UML terms, a one-to-many relationship can be a composition or an aggregation. In a relational model, I have no choice but to model those as separate tables. But in a document model, I can do separate documents per object or roll them all together - the choice is usually based on how I want to query the data.

So your first assertion is partially true - in a document store, you have the option of nesting all your related data, but you don't have to. Also note that because MarkLogic is schema-agnostic, it's straightforward to transform your data as your requirements evolve (corb is a good option for this). Certain requirements may require denormalization to help searches run efficiently.

Brief example - a person can have many names (aliases, maiden name) and many addresses (different homes, work address). In a relational model, I'd need a persons table, a names table, and an addresses table. But I'd consider the names to be a composite relationship - the lifecycle of a name equals that of the person - and so I'd rather nest those names into a person document. An address OTOH has a lifecycle independent of the person, so I'd make that an address document and toss an element onto the person document for each related address. From an analytics perspective, I can now ask lots of interesting questions about persons and their names, and persons and addresses - I just can't get counts of names efficiently, because names aren't in separate documents.

Answer (score 1):

I guess MarkLogic is a little atypical compared to other document stores. It works best when you don't store an entire table as one document, but one record per document. MarkLogic indexing is optimized for this approach, and handles searching across millions of documents easily that way. You will see that as soon as you store records as documents, results in Tableau will improve greatly.

Splitting documents to such small fragments also allows higher performance, and lower footprints. MarkLogic doesn't hold the data as persisted DOM trees that allow random access. Instead, it streams the data in a very efficient way, and relies on index resolution to pull relevant fragments quickly..

HTH!

Comment: I wanted to clarify this statement, because its on their site too, right "one record per document". That means a document for each patient containing its patient attributes, and  a document for each claim containing its claim attributes.